# Converting non-uniform distribution to a uniform distribution

Tags: probability

How could I convert a non-uniform random variable distribution to a uniform distribution?
Is there a formula for such a transformation?

Comment: The question to ask: what distribution does your "non-uniform random variable" follow? Then you can just apply the corresponding CDF to the nonuniforms.

Comment: I think [copula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copula_(probability_theory)) are a related concept to what you want (generalized to multivariable distributions).

Answer (score 2):

Use the [probability integral transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_integral_transform).

Answer (score 0):

If you're able to generate $X$ having a cumulative distribution function $F$, compute $U := F(X)$.